# Display popup window for a CD

Tags: html

Got a CD with a bunch of tutorials etc. done in HTML. What I want is to have a browser window open with no toolbars, fixed width/height etc. because the content is designed to fit nicely into such a window.

You can do this with window.open and put a bunch of parameters in, but this triggers popup blockers and activex warnings. Also it looks kinda bad, as the original window doesn't close without a hack that also generates problems.

Is there a nice way I can achieve this effect? I could perhaps compile an .exe to autorun on the CD to launch this, but I wouldn't know how to get an .exe to open a window with toolbars etc. turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look into creating an "[HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx)" (.HTA)

Comment: That is -exactly- what I was looking for, I'd never heard of it until you mentioned. Thanks!